# Hide past time in simple PHP timepicker

Tags: php

My first block of code finds the nearest hour and stores it in a `$nextHour` variable.

I want to use this value in my second lot of code so it only shows future time in the dropdown. How do I update my second block of code to achieve this?

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$nextHour = (intval($date->format('H'))+1) % 24;
echo $nextHour.':00'; // 5
?>

<?php
$start = "09:00";
$end = "20:00";

$tStart = strtotime($start);
$tEnd = strtotime($end);
$tNow = $tStart;
?>
<select name="callbacktime" id="callbacktime">
<?php 
while($tNow <= $tEnd){
  echo '<option value='.date("H:i",$tNow).'>'.date("H:i",$tNow).'</option>';
  $tNow = strtotime('+1 hour',$tNow);
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: inside your while loop you could `if($tNow > time())` or something along those line, or alternatively you could make sure that `$tStart` is not less than the current time

Comment: @Dale this worked perfectly - many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tStart = max([strtotime('09:00'), time()]);
```

I'd go with something like this as it saves having to do a check every loop as I previously mentioned in my comment.